# Problem with setting static IP 16.04 ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server

I am running Windows 10 along VM with ubuntu server 16.04 and I am currently trying to set a static ip for ubuntu.

[image]

So I have set up my ubuntu ip according to IP configuration of my windows, and all would work fine but when I try to download webmin, I get an error: "unable to resolve host address 'www.webmin.com'"

So what am I doing wrong? Please note I am very new to ubuntu

Comment: Your network should be `192.168.1.0` and your broadcast should be `192.168.1.255`.

Comment: still the same issue :(

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu.  Your question would be easier to read if you posted text for your configuration rather than pictures of your configuration.  It's much easier to resize the text for reading than the picture.  The text also takes less storage space and bandwidth.

Comment: What is running in VM?  Ubuntu? Windows?  The IP address in the VM regardless of if you set it to NAT or Bridged should be different than the host OS as to not cause IP conflicts.

Comment: Ubuntu runs on VM and windows runs as normal operating system

Comment: It sounds like you want to set your VM then to use Bridged mode for the network, and make sure that you give Ubuntu a different IP address than Windows or any other device on your network so that you are not conflicting with anything.

Comment: When I try to ping Ubuntu server it does give me an response, check my edited answer

Answer (score 3):

By default VirtualBox will use NAT for guest VMs, and uses an internal DHCP server to hand out ip addresses for the Virtual Machines (Usually in the 10.x.x.x network range like Qemu does). 
It looks like you want to "bridge" the guest VM (Ubuntu) with the host (Windows). Change the network settings, in VirtualBox, in the guest VM settings to use bridge, and then try again.

You also should give your Ubuntu VM a different ip address e.g. 192.168.1.105 and not the same as your Windows host 192.168.1.104
Can you ping your host 192.168.1.104 after that ? And can you ping 192.168.1.1 and 8.8.8.8 ?

Comment: I changed ubuntu vm to different ip as you have suggested (192.168.1.105 Linux) and when I ping that and connection has timed out, destination host unreachable. same goes if I try to ping 192.168.1.104 (Windows). However I can ping 192.168.1.1 and 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 1):

To set a static IP address for a VM in a LAN managed by a DHCP server, you should:

- Set the VM to obtain the IP address from DHCP server. Edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces` to contain following:

  ```
  auto enp0s3
  iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
  # remove all other lines regarding this interface (or comment them out)
  ```

  Make sure to reset your network interface:

  ```
  sudo ifdown enp0s3 && sudo ifup enp0s3
  ```
- Set the DHCP server (mostly router) to provide (or *reserve*) that IP address to the computer. This depends on your DHCP server (router).
- VirtualBox must be set to use bridged mode for that VM.

Comment: How should I set my VM to obtain IP address from DHCP server and set the DHCP to reservet that IP address?

Comment: @Przemek Updated. Unfortunately I cannot tell you how to set your router when I have no idea what type you are using.